# How do I pull all data for only the most recent date access table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in an access db. The query I am working on is meant to pull the selected fields but only the information for the most recent date. I have tried to change the criteria for the `Report Date` field to max and also to "Max" the totals. Neither of these work. So, the sql code below pulls the fields I want and sorts the data with the most recent first. This is a dirty fix to my solution and pulls way too much necessary data for what I need ( only the most recent date observations) - Overall, how do I pull all of the observations for only the most recent date. Thanks!

```
SELECT      Max(RedProjectHistorical.[Report Date]) AS [MaxOfReport Date], 
            RedProjectHistorical.ID, 
            RedProjectHistorical.[Project Name], 
            RedProjectHistorical.[Client Name], 
            RedProjectHistorical.[Internal Project Status], 
            RedProjectHistorical.[Internal Project Status Value], 
            RedProjectHistorical.[Project manager]
FROM        RedProjectHistorical
GROUP BY    RedProjectHistorical.ID, 
            RedProjectHistorical.[Project Name], 
            RedProjectHistorical.[Client Name], 
            RedProjectHistorical.[Internal Project Status], 
            RedProjectHistorical.[Internal Project Status Value], 
            RedProjectHistorical.[Project manager]
ORDER BY    Max(RedProjectHistorical.[Report Date]) DESC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT      [Report Date], 
            ID, 
            [Project Name], 
            [Client Name], 
            [Internal Project Status], 
            [Internal Project Status Value], 
            [Project manager]
FROM        RedProjectHistorical
WHERE       [Report Date] = (
                             SELECT MAX([Report Date]) 
                             FROM   RedProjectHistorical
                            )
ORDER BY    [Report Date] DESC
```

NB:  No need to add table name to each field if there's no discrepancy over which table the field belongs to.

Edit:  This will work to as the table is ordered by 'Report Date':

```
SELECT TOP 1    [Report Date], 
                ID, 
                [Project Name], 
                [Client Name], 
                [Internal Project Status], 
                [Internal Project Status Value], 
                [Project manager]
FROM            RedProjectHistorical
ORDER BY        [Report Date] DESC
```

Comment: Makes complete sense. Thanks